# How to read version 25 and above qr codes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-qrcode

There is no library available to scan version 25 and above QR codes in Flutter yet. The current maximum supported version is 24. The libraries mentioned, mobile_scanner, flutter_mobile_vision, and qr_code_scanner, all only support up to version 24.

I have checked the Flutter repository and there is no issue or pull request open to add support for version 25 and above QR codes. So, it is likely that there will not be a library available to scan these QR codes until Flutter is updated to support them.

Comment: The packages you mention are not from the google team.  They all seem to have issue systems.  File an issue, or better, fix it and submit a pull request.